# How to SSH files from a server and take those files (without downloading them) and code it so that they are uploaded to a website?

Tags: r, ssh, shiny, server

I have been given access to a bunch of files on a server and have been tasked with making it so that these files are put on some sort of website where people can visit it and access it. I have been able to SSH to the server using terminal commands and am able to view all of the files on the directory. I have tried using scp_download, however, that downloads all of the files on there which is extremely large and would ideally be avoided. Is there a way where I can take the files on the server and get them directly uploaded to a website using Shiny (R package)? If not, is there another way possible?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already discovered the R package `ssh`. You could `ssh::ssh_exec_internal()` to execute a command on the server that uploads/copies the files to the website server. How you can do that depends on the type of access you have to the website server.

If you have ssh access to the website server as well, your command could look something like this:

```
ssh::ssh_exec_internal(ssh_session,
                       "scp file remote_username@website_server_ip:/directory")
```

Comment: Is there a reason you did ssh::ssh:: ? Like why did you do it twice I mean

Comment: Also, I don't really have any access to the website itself (other than knowing the URL) so am I able to do a file transfer to that or should I just make a website on my own?

Comment: comment #1:  that was just a typo. comment #2:  If you don't have access to the website server, how were you planning on uploading any data to it? Usually you can use SFTP to upload data to a server hosting a website. In that case the strategy above should work. If you only have FTP access you'd use the `ftp put ...` instead of `scp`.